# how to find html div size +android webview

Tags: android, html, webview

how to find the size of a particular div element of a html page through java code.
im displaying a webpage using android webview and i want to know the size of a particular div which contains text data .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Note: Be careful when using addJavascriptInterface for security reasons.